# Is there a Function that runs before the bot gets closed

Tags: python, discord.py

Is there a Function that runs before the bot gets closed

Ex.

```
@bot.event()
async def on_close(ctx):
    export_files()
```

I'm making a bot that reads all the new messages and adds them to the author's list of words and when the command `.get_word_count` gets called all of the words that the author has sent will be shown

```
im: 98
under: 1
the: 1
water: 1
please: 1
help: 1
me: 1
test: 124136624745687697698608
```

the reason I'm storing the data is that it's more efficient to store and start a new read rather than going through all of the channels and get the word counts

Comment: Do you need it to be a coroutine? If not, you can just have some code after the `bot.run()`

Comment: And even if a coroutine is needed, if it doesn't need the Discord API (e.g. interactions with one's own database) it could still run after `bot.run()` by running an async loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [on_disconnect event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_disconnect). However, do note that it might trigger when no connection was already established, if establishing one fails.

Hoewever I haven't really understood what your use case is and what you need on_disconnect for. There might be a better way.

Comment: this might not be what I was looking for but after a little bit of searching it could do as a temporary solution

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found yet is to subclass [commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#bot) and override the [close method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.Client.close)

```py
class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    async def close(self):
        pass # you can also use attributes (even custom ones) using self.attr

bot = MyBot(command_prefix="!")
```

This would be well suited if you need a coroutine