# atexit module not working when stopped with vsCode

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, roles, atexit

I am coding a discord bot in discord.py. I want it to change the role of the bot to show it's offline when the code is stopped. Here's the relevant code:

```py
import atexit, signal

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def exit_handler(self):
        print("stopped!")
        guild = self.get_guild(SERVER_ID)
        role = utils.get(guild.roles, name="Bot Offline")
        member = guild.get_member(BOT_USER_ID)
        await member.add_roles(role)

atexit.register(client.exit_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, client.exit_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, client.exit_handler)
```

exit_handler isn't running when stopped with vsCode. I did not get an error message. I Tried running it in IDLE as well.

Comment: do you get error message? Show it in question (not in comments) Is this working when you run without `VS Code`? Maybe `VS Code` use this `atexit` to catch exit and it can block access. Or maybe `atexit` is executed when all objects are already removed from memory. Or maybe `atexit` can't run w `async`. I think `discord` has own function to run something when yo `close` connection. Probably you have to create function `on_close()`

Comment: [python - Is there a way to run an asyncio coroutine using atexit? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640988/is-there-a-way-to-run-an-asyncio-coroutine-using-atexit)

Comment: [asyncio-atexit · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/asyncio-atexit/)

Comment: @furas do you mean that `async def on_close()` would execute on close?

Comment: When you stop a program with VSCode, you don't get SIGTERM or SIGINT - the code just literally stops dead.

Comment: @MarkRansom how do I make it run the code anyways?

Comment: You need to find another way to stop your program.  Not sure how you'd do that offhand, maybe a `kill` command?

Comment: It seems it has `on_disconnect` instead of `on_close`. Or you may create own function `close()` [python - Is there a Function that runs before the bot gets closed - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69088810/is-there-a-function-that-runs-before-the-bot-gets-closed).

Comment: `VS Code` (and `IDLE`, `PyCharm`) is only tool to develop code - if code is working then you don't need `VS Code` to run it. And then you don't have problem with `atexit`

Comment: @furas `on_disconnect` didn't work either

Comment: well, as I said before. `IDE` is only tool to develop and you don't need it to run code - so if it finished code then stop using `IDE`, and if you write code then you will have to test it outside `IDE`. And if you still want to test it in `IDE` then you may have to ask author(s) of IDE for modification - or you would have to digg in IDE's source code to create modification, and this is not easy task. It is much easier to test code in normal terminal in system